# Select Type UNION RESULT doesn't appear in the output of Explain statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, union, explain

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT actor_id,
(SELECT 1 FROM sakila.film_actor WHERE film_actor.actor_id =
der_1.actor_id LIMIT 1)
FROM (
SELECT actor_id
FROM sakila.actor LIMIT 5
) AS der_1
UNION ALL
SELECT film_id,
(SELECT @var1 FROM sakila.rental LIMIT 1)
FROM (
SELECT film_id,
(SELECT 1 FROM sakila.store LIMIT 1)
FROM sakila.film LIMIT 5
) AS der_2;
```

I was reading about using EXPLAIN, and the explain result for this query had a row with select_type as UNION_RESULT.
However, I don't get this row. Can someone help me understand this behavior?

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5   100.00  NULL
3   DERIVED actor   NULL    index   NULL    idx_actor_last_name 182 NULL    200 100.00  Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  film_actor  NULL    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   der_1.actor_id  1   100.00  Using index
4   UNION   <derived6>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5   100.00  NULL
6   DERIVED film    NULL    index   NULL    idx_fk_language_id  1   NULL    881 100.00  Using index
7   SUBQUERY    store   NULL    index   NULL    idx_unique_manager  1   NULL    2   100.00  Using index
5   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    rental  NULL    index   NULL    idx_fk_staff_id 1   NULL    15005   100.00  Using index
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was reading about using EXPLAIN, and the explain result for this query had a row with select_type as UNION_RESULT. However, I don't get this row.

`UNION ALL` without any additional operation over a summarized dataset does not need `UNION_RESULT`. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107